# BindingList of Interface Type

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, bindinglist

I’ve been having a bit of difficulty with data bindings.  I have a `BindingList(Of IDataItem)`, the list is populated with two class types that both implement the `IDataItem` interface but only one implements the `INotifyPropertyChange` interface.  As you can guess I am using a `DataGridView` control bound to the `BindingList` to display the data.  I am having a problem where any property changes make behind the scenes are not being reflected by the `DataGridView` control unless the control is redrawn.

Any suggestions?  Do both classes need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChange` interface? Does the `BindingList` not work with an interface type, must a class type be used?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm curious why you are sticking 2 different items in the BindingList.

Second, if the class does not implement INotifyPropertyChange, changes will NOT be reflected in your grid.

Third, not sure how the BindingList would work with a interface type. I would think it would inspect the type to see if it implements INotifyProretyChanged, which IDataItem (interface) cannot implement another interface... can it? (EDIT: I think it actually can)